# ASP .NET MVC 3 Design Problem (Loading data via Ajax)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jstree

I have a class Category, that represents products category... 
So I created a View that shows a Treeview with my Categories on left ...
When user select a TreeView Node, I´d like to show all the Category data in the same Page/View (On right)

What I did so far is load the JQuery TreeView via Ajax... And added a click event on each TreeView Node...
The click calls, via Ajax, the selected Category, like that (CategoryController):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetCategory(string idCategory)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var _category = _categoryRepository.Get(Convert.ToInt16(idCategory));

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())                
                return Json(_category, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

So, I got the Category JSON on client, and have to manually fill all the fields ...

Is that the right/best way to do that?
Am I missing something?

Thanks so far

Paul

Comment: Are you using Bassistance JQuery TreeView plugin?

Comment: Never used Jstree, but I suppose it would require from you to create an action which returns **[JSON data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult.aspx)** containing category items, instead of your default view (unless it actually represents your JSON data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve that using [KnockoutJs](http://knockoutjs.com/) with mapping plugin... It work great!

Thanks anyway...

Paul

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JSTree, you can use the [JSON_DATA](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data) plugin to return JSON data from your server and have JSTree build your nodes for you.  I don't know what your `_category` object looks like, but the documentation provides the structure that JSTree expects.

```
{ 
    data : "node_title", 
    // omit `attr` if not needed; the `attr` object gets passed to the jQuery `attr` function
    attr : { id : "node_identificator", some-other-attribute : "attribute_value" }, 
    // `state` and `children` are only used for NON-leaf nodes
    state: "closed", // or "open", defaults to "closed"
    children: [ /* an array of child nodes objects */ ]
}
```

If you can't return data in this format, then you'll have to render the tree nodes manually as you're doing it now.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but My jstree is ok already! Its working perfectly... My question is about the other part... Whats the best way to fill the category attributes when i click in some Node, in the same view that TreeView was built!

Comment: David, I am currently stuck in pulling the nodes from controller, can you provide an example that shows how you fill the data, state, and children in the controller? I will be really appreciative

Comment: David, or Paul can you give a simple example of how to return the json data from server side code ?